# Two factor authentication in Xamarin Forms using the email method

Tags: email, authentication, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Hi everyone I hope are having a great day. I am trying to integrate 2 factor authentication every time the user logs in into my app I want to  send an email with a random code to the user to verify their identity. Is there a way to do his in Xamarin forms?

What other alternative 2f methods I could implement in Xamarin forms?

Comment: this is usually a function of your authentication mechanism backend, not something that is implementing in the app itself

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the response. Can you guide me on how I achieve that ? I am still a newbie .

Comment: No.  I have no idea what authentication mechanism you are using.

Answer (score 0):

so the logic for 2F Auth is when the user Login with their credentials your backend needs to send code to the user either with email or SMS and after your backend verifies it then you should navigate the user to the next screen until then you have to show 2F screen to the user.